# Can I use material design lite extensions in my ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, material-design, material-design-lite

I need more components to develop a ruby on rails application. Could I use mdl-ext components including them directly in my assets folder because there is no gem for installing it through the bundle installer.

Material design lite extensions are present here https://github.com/leifoolsen/mdl-ext

And I'd like to use it together with material-design-lite present here 
https://rails-assets.org/#/components/mdl.
Note! Material design lite I am using it already.

If this is possible which is the best way to include it in the assets pipeline?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: In the end I switched to use bootstrap. But I think your answer is good. I will flag it as the answer. If someone else will come with others options is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

I'm using MDL with the gem `material_design_lite-sass`, and I included mdl-ext by downloading the files `mdl-ext.js` and `mdl-ext-eqjs.css` from the `lib` directory of the GitHub repository. I also downloaded `eq.js` from the `build` directory of the [eq repository](https://github.com/Snugug/eq.js). See the readme of mdl-ext for more info about that. (don't worry about the minified files - the asset pipeline will minify for you)

Then I put each of these files in their `javascripts` or `stylesheets` directories under `vendor/assets` in my Rails app.

Finally I added the require statements in the asset manifest files to include them in the asset pipeline:

```
// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require eq
//= require mdl-ext
```

and

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

@import 'mdl-ext-eqjs';
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to npm install it, you can just use it like you would any other css framework (bootstrap etc). Put below in the head section of your application layout file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?
family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
```

then use things like btn the way you would write normal html with there custom css classes

```
<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-
 ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">
 Button
</button>
```

https://getmdl.io/started/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer maverick5, but I am already using material design lite. What I want to do is to use the extension present at the link posted in the question together with material design lite. Do u think I could have conflicts between the 2 libraries? And if not which is the best way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for using [Material Design Lite with Ruby](https://github.com/rubysamurai/material_design_lite-sass).

In Gemfile add:

```
gem 'material_design_lite-sass'
```

In /app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss add:

```
@import 'material';
```

Note, if your extension is not 'scss' make sure you read rubysamuria's detailed instructions.

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js add:

```
//= require material
```

Note that components work with this. You can even add them individually if preferred.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for how to use Material Design Lite in Rails, it asks for how to use Material Design Lite Extensions.